# How to customize civicrm/participant/add?

Tags: civievent

I need to customize civicrm/participant/add, but I'm finding it's not as simple as customizing my extension's copy of CRM/Event/Form/Participant.php. All I've done so far is make the copy, and I'm getting errors I don't understand.

The form actually loads and processes correctly, except for a 'Could not find valid value for cid' error. I've traced the error to the cid retrieval in civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/Tab.php :

if ($context == 'standalone') {
      $this->_action = CRM_Core_Action::ADD;
    }
    else {
      $this->_contactId = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('cid', 'Positive', $this, TRUE);

I've verified that context='standalone' in the URL, so I don't understand why that line is even executed.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about what the customization you want to do is?  There are many ways to customize CiviCRM - hooks/extensions, overrides, .extra.tpl files, etc - and if you tell us what you're trying to do we can help figure out the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks for asking. In general, I'm 'deriving' a tournament extension from the event class. I want my version of the participant add form to (so far):

1) Hide Event Source & 
2) Default record_contribution to 0.

I've got my 'derived' version doing that, but I'm baffled by the Could not find valid value for cid' errors.

Comment: do you have the code of your extension already published on github or somewhere we can have a look?

Comment: It would useful to know what guide have you followed to create your extensions, the recommended steps to create an extension or modify built-in core features can be found here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension?desktop=true and here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in%2C+Profile%2C+Contribution+and+Event+Registration+Screens?desktop=true . As you are motioning a **copy** and **customization** of a Civi's php core files, I don't believe that's the best approach to move further.

Comment: Xavier: Thanks for asking. Yes, I have published my 'alpha' version to https://github.com/agloa/tournament . My first 'clone' of Event/Form/Participant.php is under wordpress/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/org.agloa.tournament/CRM/Tournament/Form/ and tournament/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/org.agloa.tournament/templates/CRM/Tournament/Form/.

Comment: Andrei: Yes, I have been following the guide of https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension?desktop=true, but I was unaware of https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension?desktop=true, so I'll start studying that. Many thanks!